# Javascript edit cookie's part value on click and reload page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the content of a cookie when the user click on a button, and refresh the page after this.
My cookie is named `cookieConsent` and has the content `{"isCookieBarHidden":true,"cookiePreferences":{"functional":true,"userPreferences":true,"analytics":true,"advertisements":true}}`

I'm trying to change `"isCookieBarHidden":true` to `false` on click on a  button with an id, and reload the page after to display again the cookiebar of a website.

Is it possible to do this with pure Javascript ? If not, how in jquery ?

Comment: Your question shows no research effort at all. Have you tried anything? What was the problem? And yes it is possible in js (in the end jquery is just a lib written in js)

Comment: I I can delete the entire cookie and rewrite it, but I would like to save the data entered by the user by editing only the first part and I can't do it. In Jquery I can do it with a click but not in javascript. Here where i am in jquery (not working) : $("#cookiebar").on('click',function(){
   var value = false,
   $.cookie('cookieConsent', 1);
   $.cookie('value',isCookieBarHidden);
}); I think i have to use something like this instead : cookieValue = $.cookie("cookieConsent", { isCookieBarHidden: 'false' });

Answer (score 1):

You can change a cookie's content the same way that you set it. Just assign new values to it and it should overwrite the old one. But if you have a cookie with a lot of properties, you can just use the **[includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)** method to check the cookie's current `isCookieBarHidden` value and then based on that retrieved value, you can use the **[replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method to change it's value to **false** or even better, toggle between **true** and **false** accordingly then reload the page like this:

```
if (document.cookie.includes('"isCookieBarHidden":true')) {
   document.cookie = document.cookie.replace('"isCookieBarHidden":true', '"isCookieBarHidden":false');
} else {
    document.cookie = document.cookie.replace('"isCookieBarHidden":false', '"isCookieBarHidden":true');
}
```

---

Check the **Code Snippet** below for a practical example of what I have described above:

```js
document.cookie = 'cookieConsent = {"isCookieBarHidden":true,"cookiePreferences":{"functional":true,"userPreferences":true,"analytics":true,"advertisements":true}}';

var dc = document.cookie;

function alertCookie() {
    alert(dc);
}

function toggleCookie() {
  
  if (document.cookie.includes('"isCookieBarHidden":true')) {
    document.cookie.replace('"isCookieBarHidden":true', '"isCookieBarHidden":false');
  } else {
    document.cookie.replace('"isCookieBarHidden":false', '"isCookieBarHidden":true');
  }
  
  location.reload();
}



document.getElementById("toggleCookie").addEventListener("click", toggleCookie);
document.getElementById("alertCookie").addEventListener("click", alertCookie);
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<button id="toggleCookie">Toggle Cookie</button>
<button id="alertCookie">Show cookies</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed explanation, I begin to understand the principle. I added `<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("clear-cookiebar").addEventListener("click", EditCookie);
</script>` in the head of my webpage and this function in a js file : `function EditCookie() {
    document.cookie.replace('"isCookieBarHidden":true', '"isCookieBarHidden":false'); 
    location.reload();
}` but it doesn't work, doesn't reload the page. Maybe because I do not specify anywhere that I want to edit the isCookieBarHidden element of the cookieConsent cookie?

Comment: Hmm.... Are you setting the cookie via a local IP or localhost? If yes, then it'll not work because as [stated here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56211), **`You can only set domain cookies for registry controlled domains, i.e. something ending in .com or so, but not IPs or intranet hostnames like localhost`**.

Comment: No it's on my online website, maybe the problem is from the `location.reload();` i tried `location.href = location.href;` but doesn't work too and the cookie is untouched if i force refresh after the click :/ i don't understand how cookies are working!

Comment: That's weird. Hold on. Let me check if there's an alaterntive for location.reload()

Comment: You don't think i have to precise cookieConsent somewhere? In any case, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Try adding `return document.cookie;` above the location.reload() but outside the if/else statement and see if that helps. In the meanwhile, let me try to fiddle with the current code.

Comment: I see true in the console with the number 2 at the left, is it normal ? Thanks for your time again ! ^^

Comment: Maybe in chrome it's weird for cookies ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36611922/3680882

Comment: @Playzare Oh ok. I think I know what/where the problem is. Inside the if statement and else statement, add `document.cookie =` before `document.cookie.replace`. I have edited the answer to include that.

Comment: And I checked the link you provided just now. That could be another reason too. Can you check the current code above (with the `document.cookie =` part too) in other browsers like Edge or Firefox and see if it works. If it does, then I will try fiddling with the code again.

Comment: Okay! Thanks ! But for my situation i need to just get the cookie itself not create it, because maybe one user will have some parameters at true/false and others all at true for example. So how can i call the `document.cookie = 'cookieConsent = {"isCookieBarHidden":true,"cookiePreferences":{"functional":true,"userPreferences":true,"analytics":true,"advertisements":true}}';` without editing it, can i use something like  `document.cookie = 'cookieConsent'` alone ? Thanks !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186671/discussion-between-andrewl-and-playzare).