# Cookie not set in iFrame

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, iframe

Scenario:

I have parent site A domain A that embeds an iframe with domain B...note that I have control of both sites. Im calling postMessage from site A that posts some information to be stored as cookie in iframe domain B. The iFrame will listen to the postMessage event and set cookie accordingly.

Domain A:

```
 var frame = document.getElementById('exampleFrame');
 frame.contentWindow.postMessage({"age":28}, '*');
```

Embedded iframe domain B:

```
window.addEventListener('message', messageReceivedEvent, false);

function messageReceivedEvent(e) {
   document.cookie("age=" + e.data.age + ";");
   console.log(document.cookie);
}
```

> console.log(document.cookie) returns nothing

The issue here is that, once i set the cookie in the **messageReceivedEvent**, it seems like the cookie is not stored in domain B. Did I missed out something?

> Note: This issue only happened in latest Google Chrome version, Firefox works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome handles cookies differently.
See Mozilla [Document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) Example #1:

- it works perfectly in Firefox
- does not work in Chrome

See this [SO thread about chrome cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349052/why-would-setting-document-cookie-not-work-in-chrome).

Also, with iFrames other people reported this Chrome "bug" here:

- [thread on bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1062162)
- or here [support.google.com thread](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/33543699?hl=en)

Not sure how to solve it, but maybe use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead?