# document.cookie not working with chrome only

Tags: javascript

I have already read other posts but I'm not working on localhost.
The **code below works on safari ie and firefox** but chrome fails.
It looks like it is completely ignored. Any suggestion is welcome.

Here is the code.

```
  document.cookie = "lang="+$('#account_lang').val()+"; path=/; samesite=none;";
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349052/why-would-setting-document-cookie-not-work-in-chrome

Comment: I see but my problem is that it does not show up in dev tools > cookies of chrome

Comment: It does not even create a new cookie and this is driving men crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Seems the newer version of each browser does not support this technique.

you should split this string into parts.

```js
   var x = "lang='1'; path='/'; samesite='none';";

 $.each(x.split(";"), function(i,obj)
    {  if(obj !== "")
        document.cookie = obj;     
    });
```

if you are using jquery then below is the code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g7ncf4d2/1/ for me it does not work :(

Comment: if u are using jquery then this is the code else need to write custom js although the context is clear